# Simple Java timer library

Tags: java, timer, scheduling, quartz-scheduler

I have need for timer code in Java with these features:

- Setting pieces of codes (`Runnable` or something like it) to execute once after a specific delay (with second precision)
- Changing the delay of an existing timer after the fact and cancelling timers.
- Using a thread pool (so no `java.util.Timer`)

I've looked into using Quartz, but it appears to be simply too large.

Is there a smallish library that does this? Or can I actually use Quartz? Or how would I implement it myself, using `ScheduledExecutor`?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't quite ask this question but the only thing you seem to want that Java timers aren't giving is thread pooling, and while I never got around to using the answers I got they seem to address that

[Can I saturate a program with Timer objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162461/can-i-saturate-a-program-with-timer-objects)

Answer (score 1):

Look at this post : [Java Timer vs ExecutorService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409932/java-timer-vs-executorservice)

> ```
> public <V> ScheduledFuture<V> schedule(Callable<V> callable,
>
>                 long delay, TimeUnit unit);
>
> public ScheduledFuture<V> scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable command,
>
>                 long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit);
>
> public ScheduledFuture<V> scheduleWithFixedDelay(
>
>                 Runnable command, long initialDelay,
>
>                 long delay, TimeUnit unit);
> ```

Comment: It's what I use now, but I need the ability to change the delay of existing timers to proceed.

Comment: @Bart : ok i understood that you want to change the delay dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Look at:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html